# If $f$ is a continuous function then Argmax of $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $I=[a,b]$ a closed real interval

Let $f: I \to R$ be a continuous function

Let $y : I \to I$ be a function such that $\forall x \in I:$
$$
\sup_{t \in [a,x]}f(t) = f(y(x))
$$
I would like to know if $y$ is a continuous function.

Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking no, think of a function that increases then decreases then increases again and once it increases again it goes higher than it did before.  The argmax is going to have to jump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of $\sin(x)$ on $[\pi,3\pi]$.  The argmax starts out at $\pi$ and stays there until $x\geq 2\pi$ at which point it jumps to be greater than $2\pi$.

Comment: the max is $0$ between $\pi$ and $2\pi$ then for $x>2\pi$ it starts from $0$ again, or am i wrong?

Comment: The max is $0$ between $\pi$ and $2\pi$ so the argmax is $\pi$ there.  But once $x>2\pi$ the max goes from $\pi$ to $x$ whatever it is, and so the argmax is not continuous.

Comment: Why would somebody downvote my perfectly correct answer?  That's really lame.

Comment: i haven't downvote you, i doubt of my assert and maybe i was not clear in my question

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @MateyMath Thanks for letting me know it wasn't you that downvoted me.  Personally I never downvote anybody unless I give a reason why.  Anyway, I'll live.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(t) = 1$ for all $t \in   I$  and choose an arbitrary discontinuous function  $y : I \to I$.

This rejects your claim!

Comment: thanks for your answer